# Singleton class for moving heap to stack

Tags: c++, singleton, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have written some class that moves heap allocated stuff to stack (hopefully :) ). This calss is singleton because only this class should be responsible for holding and managing part of stack. My question is: Is my code correct? Code is correct in the sense of programming (no compile errors, no memory errors and leaks (checked by valgrind)). But does the code really moves heap to stack? Here's the code:

stack.hpp:

```
class CStack{
public:
  void* getAlloc(long);
  static CStack* Instance();

private:
  static bool _data[5*sizeof(double)];
  static CStack* m_pInstance;

  CStack(){};
  CStack(const CStack&);
  CStack& operator=(const CStack&);
};
```

stack.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stack.hpp"

CStack* CStack::m_pInstance = 0;

bool CStack::_data[ 5*sizeof(double) ] = { 1 };

CStack* CStack::Instance(){
  if (!m_pInstance)
    m_pInstance = new CStack;
  return m_pInstance;
}

void* CStack::getAlloc(long size){
  std::cout << "  CStack::getAlloc, " << _data << std::endl;
  _pos+=size;
  return &_data[0];
}
```

store.hpp

```
class CStore{
public:
  CStore();
  double* myAddr();
  void toStack();
  void out();
  ~CStore();
private:
  double *_data;
  bool _stack;
};
```

store.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "store.hpp"
#include "stack.hpp"

CStore::CStore(){
  _data = new double[4];
  _data[0] = 0.1;
  _data[1] = 1.1;
  _data[2] = 2.1;
  _data[3] = 3.1;
  _stack = 0;
}

double* CStore::myAddr(){ return _data; }

void CStore::toStack(){
  double *tmp;

  tmp = (double*)CStack::Instance() -> getAlloc(4*sizeof(double));

  memcpy(tmp, _data, 4*sizeof(double));
  delete [] _data;
  _data = tmp;
  _stack = 1;
}

CStore::~CStore(){
  if (!_stack)
    delete [] _data;
}

void CStore::out(){
  std::cout << _data[0] << " " << _data[1] << " " << _data[2] << " " << _data[3] << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "stack.hpp"
#include "store.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(){
  CStack::Instance();
  CStore a;
  double stack;

  cout << &stack << endl;
  cout << "Adresa a " << a.myAddr() << endl;
  a.out();

  a.toStack();
  cout << "Adresa a " << a.myAddr() << endl;
  a.out();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because internally you are using m_pInstance on the heap then surely the other parts are also allocated on the heap?

Comment: `CStack* CStack::Instance(){ if (!m_pInstance) m_pInstance = new CStack; return m_pInstance;}` implies that your object lives on the heap (see the non-placement `new`?).

Comment: >> But does the code really moves heap to stack?  It moves stuff to a collection called stack, but the collection itself is on the heap so no.

Comment: I was afraid of it, because written addresses was far from address of var stack. I hope I could solve it by declare CStack::_data static, I was wrong. Is there any possibility to have singleton class that manages program stack?

Comment: How well do you understand the distinction between heap and stack? Are you aware that stack is a scarce resources in some systems and that using too much can get you into trouble? Do you know if your platform is one of those? How much memory do you intended to manage this way? And above all, ***why*** do you want to do this---we can't give good advice unless we know the reasoning behind this desire.

Comment: Anyway thank you all for quick responses, I really appreciate it. Regarding the last dmckee comment: Maybe I do not distinct correctly between heap and stack.I know that stack is scarce resource, but I will use the program on my own and transport it between mingw and linux (i could set stack unlimited). I am about to store much much memory in stack. About last remark: I wrote CFD app based on storing vars in stack, which was programmer uncomfortable, than I rewrote it to use heap causing the app running twice slower. Above approach is good "hybrid" I mean. Thanks in advance

Comment: Using the heap *per se* shouldn't be a lot slower than using the stack. You might be better off looking for *why* your heap implementation is so much slower. The "obvious" solution for storing some object on the sack is to allocate a big buffer right after startup and overload `new` on the candidate objects to call a custom allocator that uses that buffer, but that's a lot of work and fraught with danger, nor does it solve the *"needed to know how how much memory we need at compile time"* problem.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I tend to similar solution. To store some "large" object or objects (yet CStack::_data) on stack which could access only above singleton class CStack and could do all the necessary memory management. You are right that app using heap allocs shouldn't be so slow, anyway stack is faster at least little bit. May be I will create new thread.

Comment: alloca() can you you stack memory, but I wouldn't worry about this for now.

Answer (score 0):

No it's utter nonsense.

First of all this code doesn't even use the stack (as long as we are speaking of the execution stack), and you clearly misunderstood the Singleton desing pattern.

You use Singleton, when you only need a single instance in your program, but you want to grant access to all functions to that single instance. Its like a global variable, but you can restrict the access.

Second, if you need to use casting in C++ like:

```
tmp = (double*)CStack::Instance() -> getAlloc(4*sizeof(double));
```

You've clearly gone wrong. Don't use `void*` in C++ for now. You can use it later, when you've gotten better, not for now.

The main question WHY do you wan't to move variables to the stack? if you simply want to allocate dynamicly, why still limiting it to the scope, use smart pointers, like std::auto_ptr.

if you want to create a stack, and use that to store your doubles you can write:

```
#include <vector>

int foo()
{
  std::vector<double> stack;

  // push values on the stack
  stack.push_back(1.1);
  stack.push_back(1.2);
  stack.push_back(1.3);

  // remove values from the stack
  stack.pop_back();
  stack.pop_back();
  stack.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: I think your vector stuff is going to confuse this person a lot.  That's a vector named stack and is declared local (on the stack) and is used like a stack, but all the values go on the heap.

Comment: Latter I relized the CStack is created dynamically on heap hence all its contet. I thought that creating CStack on stack would help but its violating singleton pattern, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284561/singleton-class-on-callstack. I have made some workaround that I will post later to subject it to criticism.