# Singleton class on callstack

Tags: c++, singleton, callstack

is there some approach to make singleton class initialize on programs stack (hence members variables also)?
I have tried following, both were failed:

1)

```
class CStack{
public:
  void* getAlloc(long);
  static CStack& Instance(){
    static CStack theStack;
    return theStack;
  }

private:
  bool _data[100];

  CStack(){};
  CStack(const CStack&);
  CStack& operator=(const CStack&);
};
```

2)

```
class CStack{
public:
  void* getAlloc(long);
  static CStack* Instance();

private:
   CStack(){};
   CStack(CStack const&){};
   CStack& operator=(CStack const&){};
   static CStack* m_pInstance;
};

CStack* CStack::m_pInstance = NULL;

CStack* CStack::Instance(){
  if (!m_pInstance)   // Only allow one instance of class to be generated.
      m_pInstance = new CStack;

   return m_pInstance;
}
```

first failed due to non-placement new initialization(m_pInstance = new CStack;), second due to lazy initialization. Could, please, someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: `Could, please, someone help me?` - Yes, don't use singletons.

Comment: Having a singleton created on the stack is kind of useless, as it's not really a singleton is it? And the singleton will only be valid in the scope it was created in, and can't be used from any other place.

Comment: I don't see a `CStack` class being created "on the stack" in either instance so I don't really understand the problem.

Comment: Why having singleton on stack violate singleton pattern? Having singleton in main() scope would solve lifetime and could be accessed from any place or I miss something.

Comment: @Xeo: Why not? Singletons are often great!

Comment: @TauWich - `main` scope is only accessable within the function `main()`. Singleton should be accessible from everywhere.

Comment: @TauWich: If it's on the stack, then (1) it's a local, which would not be visible outside of `main` -- particularly not in functions it calls! -- unless you passed it to them; and (2) you'd be hard pressed to create a singleton on the stack without having a constructor anyway -- at best, you'd have a *pointer* on the stack.  And once you have an accessible constructor, it's not a singleton anymore, cause you can create as many as you want.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe singletons and global variables share the same issues.

Comment: @AndersK. Only if you don't use them correctly. If you use singletons as a way to store state then you don't get it. (I'm just saying singletons can be very useful, not that they should be used more often.)

Comment: Either way, if you're passing it around and you want only one, then just *don't create a second instance*.  You really don't need a singleton unless you intend to splatter `CStack::instance()`s all over your code.

Comment: @Anders K.: not really an answer, is it? What issues?

Comment: You would help people trying to answer this is you included a pointer to your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279964/singleton-class-for-moving-heap-to-stack. Mind you, I still think you are going down the wrong track: figure out why the heap version is so slow and *fix that* rather than introducing more complexity in the belief that the stack is magically fast. Really.

Comment: @dmckee: True, absolutely true. Going deeper to the problem, I realized that I have introduced global variables (known at compile time) used also in for cycles! I am using intel icpc compiler, so with switches kind of unroll and -xSSE3. Compiler PROBABLY vectorized for cycles and applied on some primitives SSE "parallelism". Moreover the program was small enough to fit in cache, so PROBABLY transfer data from heap to stack would cause more overhead. I will do some test to prove above idea. I have made some workaround on original topic, I will post it later to subject it to criticism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of singleton is not to rely on when and where it is initialized. The first access would initialize the object, and all subsequent access would yield the same object.

If you put the object on the stack - it will be destructed when the stack is closed (you exit out of the scope), thus future accesses would yield either invalid or a different object, but not the same (as you're out of the scope for the same one).

Thus, by definition of singleton, it cannot be done.

Now, if you explain the problem you're trying to solve, someone may help you with solving it in some more sensible way.

Comment: Nice to see a helpful answer for a change instead of a 'singletons be evil' type of answer.

Comment: It took me while to understand you answer. Anyway the concept of programs stack doesnt fit for singleton. Many thanks.

Comment: cHao's comment also helped me:If it's on the stack, then (1) it's a local, which would not be visible outside of main -- particularly not in functions it calls! -- unless you passed it to them; and (2) you'd be hard pressed to create a singleton on the stack without having a constructor anyway -- at best, you'd have a pointer on the stack. And once you have an accessible constructor, it's not a singleton anymore, cause you can create as many as you want.

Comment: @TauWich: Yes and no, it depends. You could make `main` a friend of your class, binding the semantics of the both. The `main` function would create the object and store the pointer in the global static. With `main` being under your control this is not that different from any other free function being part of the interface... of course, I would not really recommend this as there is no clear advantage over any other of the options and has potential problems...